# Avoid object_id warning when using andand in Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby, andand

When I load andand in Ruby 1.9 I get the warning

```
andand.rb:111: warning: undefining 'object_id' may cause serious problem
```

Does anyone know a way, other than modifying andand to not remove object_id, to avoid this warning?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want to suppress the warning or avoid the serious problems it's warning come with undefining object_id?

Comment: I really just want to suppress the warning.  I'm comfortable with the module's functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're in luck - it was just patched with [a fix for this issue](http://github.com/raganwald/andand/commit/83da29755eda5f88e7fbc18004fd7d06f791b294).

Unfortunately, as of 2011-03, the gem has not been published with this patch in place.  However, there is a fork which sole purpose is to have that patch: [ryansch-andand](http://rubygems.org/gems/ryansch-andand)

Good news! Version v1.3.3 was pushed to RubyGems on 2012-03-28, and includes this fix.

Comment: @Wayne - is there a reason that link points to a massive jpg?

Comment: No worries. And, as it happens, I've just discovered that a fix is live.